Numerically solving a large dimensional non-standard quadratic matrix equation
I need to solve a system of two coupled matrix equations in $X$ and $P$,
$$
X = A_1 + A_2P \\
P = A_3X + A_4PX.
$$
In the above equations, $A_1$-$A_4$ are known matrices and $X,P$ are unknown. All matrices are squares of dimension $n\times n$, where $n = 1400$.
I have tried several methods for solving these equations, including the following:

Guess $P^{(0)}$.
Use the first equation to produce a guess for $X$ by solving $X^{(0)} = A_1 + A_2 P^{(0)}$.
Update the guess for $P$ by solving the Sylvester equation $-A_4P^{(1)}X^{(0)} + P^{(1)} = A_3 X^{(0)}$.
If $\lVert P^{(1)} - P^{(0)}\rVert$ is small enough, I stop, otherwise I set $P^{(0)} = P^{(1)}$ and start over again.

This algorithm, however, keeps diverging. I tried a slightly different algorithm by substituting the first equation in the second to get the following quadratic equation:
$$0 = A_4^{-1}A_3A_1 + A_4^{-1}(A_3A_2 - \mathbf I)P + PA_1 + PA_2P \\
\implies 0 = B_1 + B_2 P + PB_3 + PB_4P,$$
where $B_1 = A_4^{-1}A_3A_1, B_2 = A_4^{-1}(A_3A_2 - \mathbf I), B_3 = A_1, B_4 = A_2$. I tried solving this system using the following iterative scheme:

Guess a value $P^{(0)}$.
Solve the Sylvester equation for $P^{(1)}$: $$0 = B_1 + B_2 P^{(1)} + P^{(1)}(B_3 + B_4 P^{(0)})$$.
If $\lVert P^{(1)} - P^{(0)}\rVert$ is small enough, I stop, otherwise I set $P^{(0)} = P^{(1)}$ and start over again.

This algorithm unfortunately diverges as well.
I would greatly appreciate any suggestions on how I may approach this problem. For context, these equations come from a macroeconomic model, in particular a control-theory problem in which typically there are both stable and unstable paths and the desired solution is the stable saddle path.

Are there any symmetries or other structures in the involved matrices? Namely, maybe those can exploited to formulate your problem to something similar as an algebraic Riccati equation.

Unfortunately no. Apart from being symmetric and invertible, there are no other useful properties of matrices $A_1$-$A_4$ that I can think of.

Which variables are symmetric? All, only $P$ or also others? Please update this also in the problem description of your question.

It seems that if there are some additional unstated conditions, this might
be just the standard control theory, but perhaps you are trying to do
something nonstandard, as hinted at in the title. I would have asked for
clarification but I lack the reputation so am giving this as an answer.
Edit: After clarification by the poster, have added a solution for the more general conditions required in the update below.
In your second algorithm, you derive and seek to solve $%
0=B_{1}+B_{2}P+PB_{3}+PB_{4}P$. This looks very like the continuous-time
case of the algebraic matrix Ricatti equation (CARE), which would be written
(Wikipedia)  $%
A^{T}P+PA-PBR^{-1}B^{T}P+Q=0$. Comparing with yours, $%
Q=B_{1}=A_{4}^{-1}A_{3}A_{1}$,  $-BR^{-1}B^{T}=B_{4}=A_{2},$ and $%
A=B_{3}=A_{1}$. This is consistent with your first equaton being for the
closed loop transfer matrix. But then $B_{2}$ and $B_{3}$ would need to be
transposes, which is not obvious.
Under the assumption that your equations
can be cast into a standard form, then there are standard solvers. If you
have access to Maple, it solves the slightly more general $%
A^{T}P+PA-(S+PB)R^{-1}(S+PB)^{T}+Q$, by calling the SLICOT
library. SLICOT routines are also accessible also
via Matlab and (perhaps?) Mathematica. These algorithms find stable
solutions with $P$ symmetric. An algorithm that uses eigendecomposition of a
matrix of double the dimensions is given on the Wikipedia page, though $Q$
and $BR^{-1}B^{T}$ need to be symmetric.
Update with solution
To solve:
$$
0  = B_{1}+B_{2}P+PB_{3}+PB_{4}P \\
X  = B_{3}+B_{4}P
$$
for $P$ and $X$, where $X$ is stable (eigenvalues have negative real parts).
($B_{3}=A_{1}$ and $B_{4}=A_{2}$ are symmetric, but the others are not.)
Given that the usual assumptions don't apply, we need a slight modification
of the Hamiltonian matrix method on the Wikipedia
page. The
algorithm is as follows.

Construct the $2n\times 2n$ matrix $Z$, which in block form is

$$
Z=
\begin{bmatrix}
B_{3} & B_{4} \\ 
-B_{1} & -B_{2}
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Find its eigenvalues and eigenvectors.

Sort the eigenvalues in order of increasing real part. If there are at
least $n$ with negative real part, there is a solution in which $X$ is
stable. Select the $n$ with the most negative real parts. Let the $2n\times n
$ matrix of corresponding (column) eigenvectors in block form be


$$
U=
\begin{bmatrix}
U_{11} \\ 
U_{21}
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Find the solutions for $P$ and $X$ as
$$
P = U_{21}U_{11}^{-1} \\
X = B_{3}+B_{4}P
$$

Notes:

The matrix $Z$ is not Hamiltonian unless $B_{2} = B_{3}^{T}$ and so in the
general case we are not guaranteed to find $n$ eigenvalues with negative
real parts.

The eigenvalues of $X$ are the $n$ eigenvalues of $Z$ with most negative
real parts.

The matrix $P$ is not symmetric (as it is if $Z$ is Hamiltonian).


Justification
The matrix $U$ of the eigenvectors of $Z$ means it can be diagonalized with
a similarity as follows
$$
Z=
\begin{bmatrix}
U_{11} & U_{12} \\ 
U_{21} & U_{22}
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
\Lambda _{1} & 0 \\ 
0 & \Lambda _{2}
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
U_{11} & U_{12} \\ 
U_{21} & U_{22}
\end{bmatrix}
^{-1}
$$
where we have permuted as necessary so $\Lambda _{1}$ has the most negative
eigenvalues. That is
$$
Z
\begin{bmatrix}
U_{11} \\ 
U_{21}
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
U_{11} \\ 
U_{21}%
\end{bmatrix}
\Lambda _{1}
$$
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
B_{3} & B_{4}
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
U_{11} \\ 
U_{21}
\end{bmatrix}
=U_{11}\Lambda _{1}
$$
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
B_{3} & B_{4}
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
U_{11} \\ 
PU_{11}
\end{bmatrix}
=U_{11}\Lambda _{1}
$$
$$
\left( B_{3}+B_{4}P\right) U_{11}=U_{11}\Lambda _{1}
$$
$$
B_{3}+B_{4}P=U_{11}\Lambda _{1}U_{11}^{-1}
$$
and $X=B_{3}+B_{4}P$ is similar to $\Lambda _{1}$ with the same eigenvalues.
Now consider
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
P & -I
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
B_{3} & B_{4} \\ 
-B_{1} & -B_{2}
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
I \\ 
P
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
P & -I
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
B_{3}+B_{4}P \\ 
-B_{1}-B_{2}P
\end{bmatrix}
$$
$$
=
\begin{bmatrix}
P & -I
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
B_{3}+B_{4}P \\ 
-B_{1}-B_{2}P
\end{bmatrix}
=B_{1}+B_{2}P+PB_{3}+PB_{4}P
$$
which we require to be zero. If we choose $P=U_{21}U_{11}^{-1}$ then
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
P & -I
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
U_{11} & U_{12} \\ 
U_{21} & U_{22}
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
\Lambda _{1} & 0 \\ 
0 & \Lambda _{2}
\end{bmatrix}
U^{-1}
\begin{bmatrix}
I \\ 
P
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & \ast 
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
\Lambda _{1} & 0 \\ 
0 & \Lambda _{2}
\end{bmatrix}
U^{-1}
\begin{bmatrix}
I \\ 
P
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & \ast 
\end{bmatrix}
U^{-1}
\begin{bmatrix}
I \\ 
P
\end{bmatrix}
$$
where $\ast $ is some noncritical entry. Writing the inverse $U^{-1}=V$ in
partitioned form
$$
U^{-1}
\begin{bmatrix}
I \\ 
P
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
V_{11} & V_{12} \\ 
V_{21} & V_{22}
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
I \\ 
U_{21}U_{11}^{-1}
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
V_{11}+V_{12}U_{21}U_{11}^{-1} \\ 
V_{21}+V_{22}U_{21}U_{11}^{-1}
\end{bmatrix}
$$
But we know $V_{21}U_{11}+V_{22}U_{21}=0$ or $
V_{21}+V_{22}U_{21}U_{11}^{-1}=0$ so the bottom entry is zero and we
conclude the whole expression is zero as required.

Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, $B_2$ and $B_3$ are not transposes of each other, which, as you correctly point out, makes my problem different from the algebraic matrix Ricatti equation.

Have added a solution under the more general conditions. It is always a solution to the two equations but is not guaranteed to give a stable solution, in the sense that $X$ has eigenvalues with negative real part, as I assume is required. Perhaps there are details of $A_1\ldots A_4$ that make that the case. For some random vectors I tried there were close to but not quite $n$ eigenvalues with negative real part.

$
\def\red#1{\color{red}{#1}}
\def\green#1{\color{green}{#1}}
\def\blue#1{\color{blue}{#1}}
$Rearrange the equations
$$\small\eqalign{
(1)\;\;X &= A_1 + A_2P &\quad\implies\quad P &= A_2^{-1}(X-A_1) \\
(2)\;\;P &= A_3X + A_4PX &\quad\implies\quad X &= (A_3+A_4P)^{-1}\:P \\
&&&= \Big(A_3+A_4A_2^{-1}\:(X-A_1)\Big)^{-1}A_2^{-1}\;(X-A_1) \\
&&&= \Big(\red{(A_3-A_4A_2^{-1}A_1)}+\blue{A_4A_2^{-1}}\:X\Big)^{-1}A_2^{-1}\:(X-A_1) \\
&&&= \Big(\red{B}+\blue{C}X\Big)^{-1}A_2^{-1}\:(X-A_1) \\
}$$
Construct a nonlinear matrix equation $\:F(X) = 0,\,$ where
$$\small\eqalign{
F &= X - \Big(B+CX\Big)^{-1}A_2^{-1}\:(X-A_1) \\
}$$
Calculate the differential of $F$
$$\small\eqalign{
dF
 &= dX + \Big(B+CX\Big)^{-1} \Big(C\:dX\Big)
           \Big(X-F\Big) - \Big(B+CX\Big)^{-1}A_2^{-1}\;dX \\
 &= dX + \Big(X+C^{-1}B\Big)^{-1}\,dX\,
           \Big(X-F\Big) - \Big(A_2B+A_2CX\Big)^{-1}\:dX \\
}$$
Then vectorize it and recover the Jacobian
$$\small\eqalign{
\def\l{\alpha}
\def\p{\partial}
\def\k{\otimes}
df
 &= \Big[I\k I\Big]\,dx
  + \Big[(X-F)^T\k(X+C^{-1}B)^{-1}\,\Big]\,dx
  - \Big[I\k(A_2B+A_2CX)^{-1}\,\Big]\,dx \\
J\doteq\frac{\p f}{\p x}
 &= \Big[I\k I\Big]
  + \Big[(X-F)^T\k(X+C^{-1}B)^{-1}\,\Big]
  - \Big[I\k(A_2B+A_2CX)^{-1}\,\Big] \\
}$$
The Jacobian can be used either in a gradient descent iteration
$$\eqalign{
x_{k+1} &= x_k - \l_k J_k^Tf_k \\
k &= k+1 \\
}$$
or (in the unlikely event you are able to invert it) a Newton-Raphson iteration
$$\eqalign{
x_{k+1} &= x_k - J_k^{-1}f_k \\
k &= k+1 \\\\
}$$

Since $J\,$ is $\,1400^2\times1400^2\:$ even a gradient step is not feasible in the vectorized form.
Here is the gradient step in a form using mere $\,1400\times1400\:$ matrices
$$\small\eqalign{
X_{k+1}
 \:&=\: X_k \:-\: \l_k\left[F_k
 + \Big(X_k+\red{C^{-1}B}\Big)^{-T}F_k\,\Big(X_k-F_k\Big)^T
 - \Big(\blue{A_2B}+\red{A_2C}X_k\Big)^{-T}F_k\,\right]
\\
 \:&=\: X_k \:-\: \l_k\left[F_k
 + \Big(X_k^T+\red{P}\Big)^{-1}\,F_k\,\Big(X_k-F_k\Big)^T
 - \Big(\blue{Q}+X_k^T\red{R}\Big)^{-1}\,F_k\,\right]
\\
}$$
To accelerate convergence, use one of the Barzilai-Borwein steplengths.
They can be modified to accommodate matrix variables like so
$$\small\eqalign{
\def\D{\Delta}
\D X &= X_k-X_{k-1},\qquad \D F = F_k-F_{k-1} \\
\\
\l_k^{LONG} &= \frac{\D X:\D X}{\D X:\D F}
, \qquad 
\l_k^{SHORT} = \frac{\D X:\D F}{\D F:\D F}
, \qquad 
\l_k^{MEAN} = \sqrt{\frac{\D X:\D X}{\D F:\D F}}
}$$
where a colon denotes the matrix inner product
$$\eqalign{
A:B \;=\; \sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^n A_{ij}B_{ij}
}$$
In Julia, this would  be implemented as an elementwise product followed by a sum over all elements, e.g.
α = sum(ΔX .* ΔF) / sum(ΔF .* ΔF)


You could avoid inverting the Jacobean by using a finite difference to approximate a Jacobean-vector product and a Krylov method for the linear solve. The gains in efficiency will depend on whether the spectrum of $J$ is clustered around a few points
